# Confused with class level generics parameter and method level generics parameter

Tags: java

The following is the interface signature of Comparator interface, it is a generic interface using `T` as the generics parameter.

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
 ....
}
```

The interface has a default method defined as follows:

```
    public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

This method is a generic method with 2 generic parameters, `T` and `U`, It looks to me that `T` is also defined at method level as `U`, and has no relation with the `T` in `Comparator<T>`?

But with the following code,it looks that both `T` are same? I am confused.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Inner {
    public static String getValue(File f) {
        return f.getName();
    }
    public static String getValue2(Integer i) {
        return "" + i;
    }
}

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//getValue must use File as the parameter.
        Comparator<File> fileComparator = Comparator.comparing(Inner::getValue); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This method is a generic method with 2 generic parameters, `T` and `U`, It looks to me that `T` is also defined at method level as `U`, and has no relation with the `T` in `Comparator<T>`?

Correct. In Java, a static method can't refer to the class's or interface's type parameters, because it's the same static method no matter what the type arguments are. (There isn't a `Comparator<Integer>.comparing(...)` and a `Comparator<String>.comparing(...)`, just a single `Comparator.comparing(...)`.)

So while it's totally fine for a static method to be generic, its type parameters are separate from those of the class or interface. (In this case that could be `Comparator.<Integer>comparing(...)` or `Comparator.<String>comparing(...)` or the like — note that the type argument is written *after* the dot — but in most cases you can just write `Comparator.comparing(...)` and let the compiler infer the right type arguments anyway.)

> But with the following code,it looks that both `T` are same? I am confused.

They happen to be the same, yes. `Comparator.<File>comparing(...)` returns an instance of `Comparator<File>`, so basically any use of `Comparator.<File>comparing(...)` will have a corresponding use of `Comparator<File>`. (And likewise for any other type argument, obviously.)

In this case the compiler can tell that it's `Comparator.<File>comparing(...)` and not `Comparator.<Integer>comparing(...)`, because the latter would return the wrong type; and it can therefore tell which `Inner::getValue` is meant, because only one of them has the right type to be passed into `Comparator.<File>comparing(...)`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks @ruakh for the great answer, understood now. static method's type parameters matter.